# Facing issue while using invokeAll to fetch Future object in ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, callable, invokeall

Facing below error while fetching **Future** object by using **invokeAll** Method. Iam trying to implement **ExecutorService** to call parallelly.

ERROR>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>**java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException**

Code Snippet

Main Class :

```
ExecutorService exService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
List<CallableTask> listOfTask = new ArrayList<CallableTask>();
Map<String, String> param1= params;
param1.put("catCode", "XX278293##X");
listOfTask.add(new CallableTask(param1));

List<Future<Map<String,String>>> resultSet =  exService.invokeAll(listOfTask);
for(Future<Map<String,String>> result : resultSet){
    if(result.isDone()){
        Map<String,String> response = result.get(); <<----------Facing Error in this line
    }           
}
exService.shutdown();
```

Class CallableTask:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

class CallableTask implements Callable<Map<String, String>>{
    private String name;
    private Map<String, String> params;
    public CallableTask(Map<String, String> params){    
        this.name=params.get("catCode");
        this.params =params;
    }
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> call() throws Exception {
       boolean data = false;
        //REST CALL
    Map<String, String> resultData = Collections.emptyMap();
        resultData.put("result", name+data);    
        //Getting response upto here
        return resultData;
    }
}
```

thank you in advance!!!

Comment: I don't know the answer, but out of pure curiosity, why do you call `result.isDone()`? You don't show what your code will do with any of the new Map objects, but why does it not await any of the futures? What happens if _none_ of the futures has been completed by the time the loop ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the exception happens here：you can't call `emptymap#put`:

```
Map<String, String> resultData = Collections.emptyMap();
resultData.put("result", name+data);
```

`Future#get` just reports the exception that occurs during the execution of `CallableTask`:

```
   FutureTask#report:

   private V report(int s) throws ExecutionException {
        Object x = outcome;  --Here: outcome is "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException".
        if (s == NORMAL)
            return (V)x;
        if (s >= CANCELLED)
            throw new CancellationException();
        throw new ExecutionException((Throwable)x); --Status of this task is "EXCEPTIONAL"
    }
```